# Storing keys with prefix that expire in redis

Tags: python, redis

Trying to store values that expire x amount of time with a key prefix

I'm using using redis.  I'm currently storing the values using hset

```
import redis


r = redis.StrictRedis('localhost')


for i in range(10):
    r.hset('name', i, i)


print(r.hgetall('name'))
```

I want each key to have a different expire time, as I will be storing each key individually.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This can't be done directly. You can add an expiration on the hset as a whole, but not on individual fields. If you want to do this, you can call `r.expire('name', time)`, where `time` is the number of seconds until expiration.

As an alternative, you can use `set` instead of `hset`:

```
for i in range(10):
    r.set('name:' + str(i), i, ex=time_to_expire_s)
```

This will take away some functionality, since (for example) you won't have a good way to list all keys that start with 'name:', but it will let you set expirations for keys independently.

As a second option, you can set expirations in the values of the `hset`. This requires client side logic, and Redis won't do any expunging for you; but you could do something like:

```
for i in range(10):
    r.hset(
        'name',
        i,
        json.dumps({ 'value': i, 'expiration': time.time() + time_to_expire_s })
    )
```

And then if you ever read a value whose expiration is in the past, you consider that to be a cache miss. This won't help you if you're trying to expire keys in order to free memory, but if your goal is to have the keys expire for some sort of correctness reason, this might work for you.

Comment: I do need the keys to expire as say I might get 1-2k inputs over the course of a minute.  Want to store those, call them, and then have them expire since there will be a fresh new 1-2k inputs.

Comment: I suppose, the only thing I'm still confused on is if I store them as a set as you said I run into a issue to query them.  So not sure how I would store those inputs as they come in at random individually.

Comment: What's your use case? You've explained how you want to write to Redis, but not how you want to use the data afterward.

Comment: I want to show recent searches done.  So I get the search from my search bar, store it in redis, display it to other users

Comment: How about having one `hset` per minute, and then displaying the contents of the most recent M? As in, have keys like `name + ":" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")`, and have them expire in N > M minutes, and then have application logic combine the results of the most recent M when you're working the display results.